# Overwriting css selectors in node modules

Tags: css, angular, node-modules

I read from time to time that it is bad practice to override css selectors in node_modules. Good practice is to override the stylesheets with more specific selectors in your own project. Can someone please explain to me why exactly this is bad practice.

To give you an example, I use the ngx-bootstrap datepicker and have had to adapt it for an application. For this I have added a custom theme to the bs-datepicker.css file. The bs-datepicker.css file was finally placed in the app folder, so everyone who pulls the project via gitlab will have the datepicker as custom when installing the dependencies via npm.

Could one say it depends, or is it fundamentally bad practice to extend the css of a node module or even overwrite selectors here?

Comment: when you say *The bs-datepicker.css file was finally placed in the app folder* you mean that it is located in the app folder outside of the node_modules folder? or do you mean inside of node_modeuls folder of your app folder?

Comment: Correct, it is located in the app folder, outside of the node_modules folder.

Comment: In that case it is perfectly fine, the bad use case is what @Shlok Nangia mentions in his answer

Answer (score 0):

you node module will only stay in your computer. If someone else uses your code and tries to run `npm install` , they will not get you manual css changes.

Also if you ever update your node_modules then also your changes will be overridden

Therefore you are suggested to make your changes in your code not in node modules.
You can use `::ng-deep` in your code to make changes to some css in a library

Comment: You're correct regarding the node_modules part. regarding the `::ng-deep` he'll need to use it just in case he place the *overriding* css selectors in one of his components. If he place them in a general css file he doesn't need it.